# login system with access

Tags: java, swing, ms-access, jdbc

Hello all I’m new to java and I’m  trying to get this java code to run but for some reason it’s not showing me errors in my Eclipse console.. It does have a syntax error at this line:

```
b.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
```

I have tried all the suggestions and I haven’t gotten anywhere.. I know that it's something simple but I have never had the console not display any errors before. Thanks for any help!

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Loging {
Connection con;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;

JFrame f = new JFrame("User Login");
JLabel l = new JLabel("Username");
JLabel l1 = new JLabel("password");
JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
JButton b = new JButton("Login");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public void Loging1() {
    connect();
    frame();
}

public void connect() {
    try {
        String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";// Driver needed for
                                                        // connection
        Class.forName(driver);// Class.forName(driver);

        String db = "jdbc:odbc:db1";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
        st = con.createStatement();

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

}

public void frame()
        {
            f.setSize (600,400);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setVisible(true);

            JPanel p = new JPanel();
            p.add(l);
            p.add(t);
            p.add(l1);
            p.add(t1);
            p.add(b);

            f.add(p);
            b.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {


            }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        String user = t.getText().trim();
        String pass = t1.getText().trim();

        String sql = "select user, pass from Table1 where user = '" + user
                + "'and pass = '" + pass + "'";// for sql query
        // String sql =
        // "select user, pass from Table1 where user = '"+user+"'pass = '"+pass+"'";
        // Getting the fields user and pass checks tthat both are equal to
        // each orther
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);// executes query

        int count = 0;// cont the rows for the query
        while (rs.next()) {
            count = count + 1;// if no rows are returned then no user exist,
                                // if count is = to 1 then user exist }
        }

        if (count == 1)// if = to 1 user exist
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in!");
        } else if (count > 1)// if more that one
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate user, DENIED!");
        }

        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "user not found");
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    // public static void main(String[] args) {

}
// New Loging1 ();
}
```

Comment: Annnnd... what's not working?

Comment: The `JdbcOdbcDriver` has been depreciated and your should not use it.  Something like [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) might be a more suitable solution, but you'd need to do some research

Comment: Are you able to have Eclipse format your code so it appears nicer?

Comment: You have an extra closing brace. Format your code with proper indentation and it'll be obvious to you.

Comment: That line of code is clearly incomplete, hence the syntax error.  You'd correct it by, well, completing the statement you're attempting to write.

Comment: You did not implement actionPerformed()  in the correct area http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891380/java-anonymous-class-that-implements-actionlistener

Comment: You should also have a look at [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This...

```
b.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {

}
```

is going to give you a compiler error because you've failed to fufil the requirements of the `ActionListener` interface, namely implement the `actionPerformed` method.

Something more like...

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Loging {

    Connection con;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    JFrame f = new JFrame("User Login");
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Username");
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("password");
    JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
    JButton b = new JButton("Login");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void Loging1() {
        connect();
        frame();
    }

    public void connect() {
        try {
            String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";//Driver needed for connection
            Class.forName(driver);//    Class.forName(driver);

            String db = "jdbc:odbc:db1";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
            st = con.createStatement();

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

    }

    public void frame() {
        f.setSize(600, 400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(l);
        p.add(t);
        p.add(l1);
        p.add(t1);
        p.add(b);

        f.add(p);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    String user = t.getText().trim();
                    String pass = t1.getText().trim();

                    String sql = "select user, pass from Table1 where user = '" + user + "'and pass = '" + pass + "'";//for sql query
                    //String sql = "select user, pass from Table1 where user = '"+user+"'pass = '"+pass+"'";
                    //Getting the fields user and pass checks tthat both are equal to each orther
                    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);//executes query  

                    int count = 0;//cont the rows for the query
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        count = count + 1;//if no rows are returned then no user exist, if count is = to 1 then user exist              }
                    }

                    if (count == 1)//if = to 1 user exist
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in!");
                    } else if (count > 1)//if more that one
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate user, DENIED!");
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "user not found");
                    }

                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }
                //public static void main(String[] args) {

            }
            //  New Loging1 ();
        });
    }
}
```

will at least compile (sorry, there were some other formatting issues I don't want to get into)

You should also learn how to use `PreparedStatements` see [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for more details, they are generally more flexible and safer.

The `JdbcOdbcDriver` has been depreciated and your should not use it.  Something like [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) might be a more suitable solution, but you'd need to do some research

You might also like to have a look at [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)